# Equivalent of RMySQL::dbEscapeStrings() for a Microsoft SQL Server Database

Tags: r, odbc

I've written a `shiny` application that uses a MySQL back-end to store and interact with uncontrolled user input. Inevitably, users include quotes and other special characters in free text, but I found that the function `RMySQL::dbEscapeStrings()` properly handled and escaped them. *(A far better solution than trying to handle all the special cases myself)*

Now, I need to migrate the database to Microsoft SQL server, and I've decided to use the `odbc` package because of it's compatibility with the `pool` package. **Is there an existing function in an `R` package that will properly escape strings to be passed to a MSSQL database?**

Here's an example of the behavior I want to replicate, but using a Microsoft SQL Server database instead of MySQL:

```
library(RMySQL)

## Create a character vector with some baddies
x <- c("foo ' bar", "blah \" blah ","ugh \\0 really","please \\% why")

cat(paste0(x, collapse = "\n"))
# foo ' bar
# blah " blah 
# ugh \0 really
# please \% why

conn <- RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "myDB", host = "127.0.0.1",
                          port = 3306, user = "MyUserName", password = "MyPassword")

cat(paste0(RMySQL::dbEscapeStrings(conn,x), collapse = "\n"))
# foo \' bar
# blah \" blah 
# ugh \\0 really
# please \\% why

dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DBI` generic `dbQuoteString` performs this function, just with slightly different behavior than `RMySQL::dbEscapeStrings()`.

As expected, escape sequences are slightly different based on the database -- `\0` doesn't have any significance for Microsoft SQL Server. The primary user-facing difference is that `dbQuoteString` wraps each element of the character vector with single quotes, where `RMySQL::dbEscapeStrings()` did not.

As the `odbc` package implements the generic, `odbc::dbQuoteString` will work as follows:

```
library(odbc)

conn <- odbc::dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(),.connection_string = "MyConnectionString")

x <- c("foo ' bar", "blah \" blah ","ugh \\0 really","please \\% why")

cat(paste0(odbc::dbQuoteString(conn,x), collapse = "\n"))

# 'foo '' bar'
# 'blah " blah '
# 'ugh \0 really'
# 'please \% why'

odbc::dbDisconnect(conn)
```